# Science Fiction short story with (forced) sex change

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Not as kinky as the my question suggests, but I'm trying to recall a short story I read about a couple, stranded on a planet.

If memory serves me correct, the somewhat timid wife/partner has to take medication regularly and is apparently not an intellectual match to the constantly researching male partner. Things start unraveling when she stops taking the medication though.

Turns out is that she used to be a he, and they were once colleagues on a mission together. Somehow through the drugs or some other procedure, the now husband/partner changed his colleagues sex and the medication she/he has been taking dutifully, serves to suppress any memories of her/his previous self and maintain a kind of docility in her.

I think she went back to taking the drugs after revealing that she remembered what happened, but I would love to get the title of the story and read that story again.

Comment: This has definitely been answered here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably "[Call Me Dumbo](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58985)" by Bob Shaw as per [this answered question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122815/two-men-have-to-populate-a-planet-by-themselves?noredirect=1&lq=1). The story is available on the Internet Archive [here](https://archive.org/details/1966-12_IF) for you to confirm but it matches.

- She's taking medication.
- The medicine is rendered ineffective (her son boiled the container thinking it was an egg) and the illusion stops working.
- She learns that she was once a "he" and she's being drugged to accept it.
- She chooses to go back on the medication and be a dutiful wife, in part because she knows that her partner hates what he's doing, so this is appropriate punishment for him to continue, while she will remain blissfully happy (she also blows up the ship with its organ bank so that he can't keep using other men's semen to impregnate her and will have to do it himself).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I actually wanted to go back to read the story because primarily, I couldn't remember why she would go back on the medication.